# (UNITY physics) objects stuck and bounce not working

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics, game-physics

I am using Unity and there are a few problems:

1. sometimes objects sink into each other (no bounce AND with bounce) and get stuck with no code or reason why
2. on higher force impacts, bounce does not work. the objects interact as if there was no bounce.

The issue only arises when I hit angled surfaces in a 2D environment. my physics2D material works on normal surface

Thank you for ALL help.

Answer (score 1):

`Physics Material` is what you need. Create a `Physics Material` then attach it to the Material Slot of a `Collider` that is attached to both **GameObjects**. Increase the **bounciness** to the amount that is good for you. Modifying the Dynamic and Static Frictions can also help. This all depend on what you are doing. Experiment with them.

What Physics Material looks like:
[image]

[image]

Comment: So, the issue only arises when I hit angled surfaces in a 2D environment. my physics2D material works on normal surfaces.

Comment: @Ryan Attach Physics Material to the other surface too. Not just one of them.

Comment: Both of the objects have the physics material on it and the problem still occurs

Comment: it occurs when you direct the player at the object at or after contact, otherwise the solution works. But the bug still very much exists

Comment: DAT @Programmer Art highlight circle :)

Comment: @Ryan Make an animated gif of what is going on in your scene then post it on imgur. Provide the link here. Without it, I can't tell what's going on in your scene.

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent sinking, set the Collision Detection to "Continuous" in RigidBody component. You can also combine with the mass.

Comment: this did not help my problem unfortunately